# Split a string using string.gmatch() in Lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

There are some discussions here, and utility functions, for splitting strings, but I need an ad-hoc one-liner for a very simple task.

I have the following string:

```
local s = "one;two;;four"
```

And I want to split it on `";"`. I want, eventually, go get `{ "one", "two", "", "four" }` in return.

So I tried to do:

```
local s = "one;two;;four"

local words = {}
for w in s:gmatch("([^;]*)") do table.insert(words, w) end
```

But the result (the `words` table) is `{ "one", "", "two", "", "", "four", "" }`. That's certainly not what I want.

Now, as I remarked, there are some discussions here on splitting strings, but they have "lengthy" functions in them and I need something succinct. I need this code for a program where I show the merit of Lua, and if I add a lengthy function to do something so trivial it would go against me.

Comment: `[^;]*` is perfectly happy matching zero semicolons. So lua matches zero semicolons each time it gets to a delimiter. You can use "[^;]+" instead for a slightly better result but there are reasons the http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin page of the lua-users wiki runs as long as it does when talking about splitting strings.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
local s = "one;two;;four"
local words = {}
for w in (s .. ";"):gmatch("([^;]*);") do 
    table.insert(words, w) 
end
```

By adding one extra `;` at the end of the string, the string now becomes `"one;two;;four;"`, everything you want to capture can use the pattern `"([^;]*);"` to match: anything not `;` followed by a `;`(greedy).

Test:

```
for n, w in ipairs(words) do
    print(n .. ": " .. w)
end
```

Output:

```
1: one
2: two
3:
4: four
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Your solution works perfectly! (I won't close this question yet: if somebody could explain to me why my original code returns spurious empty strings I'd be grateful.)

Comment: @NiccoloM. Remember that `*` matches zero or more, the empty string where I marked `$` in the string `one$;two$;$;four$` is also a match.

Comment: But what about `one$;$two$;$;$fo$ur$`? Why is the zero match only before `;` ? Why isn't it also after the `;`, and between every two letters?

Comment: @NiccoloM. Because `*` is greedy, it will try to match as long as possible, the non-greedy version to match zero or more is `-`.

Comment: After thinking very long about this, I now understand. I see that regexps in Ruby (and probably in other languages as well) behave in exactly the same way. Thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that LUA Patterns are not actually Regular Expressions, you will notice many differences between 'standard' regexp implementations and how LUA patterns operate.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing * to + works.

```lua
local s = "one;two;;four"
local words = {}
for w in s:gmatch("([^;]+)") do 
    table.insert(words, w) 
    print(w)
end
```

The magic character * represents 0 or more occurrene, so when it meet ',', lua regarded it as a empty string that [^;] does not exist.

Sorry for my carelessness, the `words[3]` should be a empty string, but when I run the original code in lua5.4 interpreter, everything works.

[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ab65.png)

[running result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf84g.png)
(I have to put links because of lack of reputation)

Comment: This does not give the OP's desired output, they want an empty string at index 3. `{ "one", "two", "", "four" }`

Comment: @Nifim sry,I dont read the question carefully.But when I use lua5.4 interpreter, the original code suddenly works!?

Answer (score -2):

```
function split(str,sep)
    local array = {}
    local reg = string.format("([^%s]+)",sep)
    for mem in string.gmatch(str,reg) do
        table.insert(array, mem)
    end
    return array
end
local s = "one;two;;four"
local array = split(s,";")

for n, w in ipairs(array) do
    print(n .. ": " .. w)
end
```

result:

1:one

2:two

3:four

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work as OP expected, because the empty string between `;;` isn't captured.

Comment: I see. Now I understand what you mean.