# join two string to one table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have 2 strings:

```lua
fields="a,b,c,d,e"

values="1,2,,4,5"
```

I need a table, to get the pairs values like:

```
print(result.a) -> "1"

print(result.c) -> "" (or nil)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have to work with these two strings or do you have the possibilty to use a lua table? For instance `local result = {a = 1, b = 2, c = '', d = 4, e = 5}`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907916/split-a-string-using-string-gmatch-in-lua) for starters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an opportunity to exploit generators without a for loop. The code below runs two *gmatch* generators in tandem.

```
fields="a,b,c,d,e"
values="1,2,,4,5"

fields=fields.."," ; F=fields:gmatch("(.-),")
values=values.."," ; V=values:gmatch("(.-),")

result={}
while true do
    local k,v=F(),V()
    if k==nil or v==nil then break end
    result[k]=v
end

for k,v in pairs(result) do print(k,v) end
```